# ERROR: Unable to get SHSH blobs for this device

Tags: iphone, ios16, ios16.4

Request URL set to https://gs.apple.com/TSS/controller?action=2
TSS server returned: STATUS=94&MESSAGE=This device isn't eligible for the requested build.
ERROR: TSS request failed (status=94, message=This device isn't eligible for the requested build.)
Sending TSS request attempt 1... ERROR: Unable to send TSS request
ERROR: Unable to get SHSH blobs for this device

idevicerestore --erase --latest '/home/iPhone12,3,iPhone12,5_16.4.1_20E252_Restore.ipsw'